# Dojo - how to achieve dynamic loading Wizardpane into Wizard?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am trying to add some extra `WizardPane` depends on user's choice, but unfortunatelly something went wrong. My new `WizardPane` seems to be hidden (it got `dijitHidden` css class). Here is how it looks like;

```
    dojo.require("xxx.xxx.ad_dynamic");
    newwiz = new xxx.xxx.ad_dynamic();

    this.wizard.addChild(newwiz);
    this.wizard.selectChild(newwiz, false);
```

After that code, I got only blank pane (with hidden `WizardPane`), and wizard's buttons (next, prev) are disabled. **Futhermore, when I add that piece of code into `postCreate` method, everything is fine - my wizard could reach new panel.**

What should I do to add new `WizardPane` to my `Wizard` without destroying "natural" wizard flow?

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, solution was using `placeAt`:

```
  WIZARDPANE.wizard.placeAt(WIZARD);
  WIZARD.startup();
```

and if you would like to update `next` and `prev` wizard's buttons, try this workaround:

```
  WIZARD.back();
  WIZARD.forward();
```

After that, your `next` and `prev` buttons will work well.